# How to count one to many relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

`ReporterTbl` has a one to many relationship with `AttachmentTbl`.

In `ReporterTbl`, I have an ID (101) and I can have `AttachmentTbl` more than one `Attachment`s related with `ReporterTbl.Id`

```
SELECT     
ISNULL(ReporterTbl.Id, 0) AS Id, 
CONVERT(char(10), ReporterTbl.StartDate, 101) AS StartDate, 
ISNULL(ReporterTbl.PriorityId, 0) AS PriorityId, 
ISNULL(dbo.ReporterTbl.PriorityDesc, '') AS PriorityDesc, 
 (select       
   ReporterTbl.Id, 
   COUNT(dbo.AttachmentTbl.Id) AS attachment_Id
FROM         
dbo.AttachmentTbl RIGHT OUTER JOIN
ReporterTbl ON dbo.AttachmentTbl.Id = ReporterTbl.Id
GROUP BY ReporterTbl.Id) AS IsAttachment
)
```

Basically, what I am trying to know is given `ReporterTbl.ID`, how many `Attachment`s do I have?

Table structure:

```
 ReporterTbl

    Id int   {**PrimaryKey**}
    StartDate datetime
    PriorityId int
    PriorityDesc varchar(500

    AttachmentTbl:

    AttachmentId indentity
    Id {**FK to ReproterTbl**}
    Filename
    Content
    ...
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
select r.id, count(a.id) as Count
from ReporterTbl r
left outer join AttachmentTbl a on r.id = a.id
group by r.id
```

**Note:** It is important that we are using `count(a.id)`, and not `count(*)`. This is because `count` will ignore null values when we count the results of an *expression*. If instead we use `count(*)`, SQL will count the resulting *rows*, so any rows from `ReporterTbl` that don't have a matching row in `AttachmentTbl` would return a count of 1 because we still return the row due to the left join.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to get all fields from Reported (not only `ID`), this will save you a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT  r.*,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    AttachmentTbl a
        WHERE   a.id = r.id
        ) AS AttachmentCount
FROM    ReportedTbl r
```

Comment: Is it generally faster to use this way than to use a join?  I ask because of the phrasing "save you a `JOIN`"

Answer (score 3):

> > given ReporterTbl.ID how many attachments i have.

Wouldn't it just be:

```
select count(*) from AttachmentTbl where id = @ID;
```

Comment: Sure, if you want one reporter at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I had to group by the first element in the `SELECT` clause as well as the item I am aggregating on:

```sql
SELECT p.Name, COUNT(c.PersonId) AS Count
FROM People AS p
LEFT JOIN Contacts AS c
    ON (p.Id = c.PersonId)
GROUP BY c.PersonId, p.Name;
```

I am not really sure why I had to do this, it isn't the case when using SQLite, which is what I am used to.